# Polarion ALM SDK API getWorkItem()

Tags: java, velocity, polarion, apache-velocity

I have a question about the Polarion SDK API

I am in a Project -> Documents and Pages -> Testing.
From there I created a new wiki article.
In the editing of the article I did the following:

1) created a sql query using: `#set ($sql_result = $sqlService.executeQuery("<sql query here>")`
The sql query produces an array that looks like this:

```
[[project.c_id, test_cases.c_id , test_cases count ], [project.c_id, test_cases.c_id , test_cases count ], [project.c_id, test_cases.c_id , test_cases count ], [project.c_id, test_cases.c_id , test_cases count ]]
```

2) Now I would like to iterate through this multi-dimensional array by doing this:

```
#foreach($item in $sql_result)
  $getWorkItem($item.get(0), $item.get(1)) <br>
#end
```

Unfortunately, Polarion does not appear to recognize the $getWorkItem(). I am pretty newbie at this, I'm sure I'm just calling the function incorrectly. I found the API Doc here: https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/index.html

It is in TrackerService.getWorkItem()

But I still don't know how to call the API correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the instance of TrackerService which is in the Velocity context to be able to call getWorkItem(), something like:

```
$trackerService.getWorkItem($item.get(0), $item.get(1))
```

The main point is that you cannot call a method without a base object in Velocity.